# Hyperlink call through Struts Action

Tags: java, jsp, hyperlink, struts

I want to navigate to JSP page from Hyperlink click through Stucts flow :
To call from My Jsp Page to Struts Config file below hyperlink:

```
<a href="userAction.do?page=user">User Creation</a><br />
```

In the Struts-config.xml : 
I mapped my action classes as follow :

```
<action-mappings>
    <action name="loginForm" path="/login" scope="request" type="com.soc.app.login.action.LoginAction" validate="false" parameter="page">
        <forward name="failure" path="/jsp/index.jsp" />
        <forward name="sessionexpired" path="/jsp/error.jsp" />
        <forward name="success" path="/jsp/home.jsp" redirect="false"/>
     </action>

<action path="/userAction" type="com.soc.app.users.action.userAction" scope="request" parameter="page" validate="false">
        <forward name="user" path="user"/>
</action>
```

userAction Class :

```
public userAction()
{
    System.out.println("inside userAction !!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    logger = Logger.getLogger("AdminLog");
    relativeURL="http://localhost:8080/xyz/";

}   

public ActionForward user(ActionMapping mapping,
        ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {
    System.out.println("inside UserAction");
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession)request.getSession();
    String url = "";
    LinkedHashMap<String,String> links = (LinkedHashMap<String,String>)session.getAttribute("links");


    String requestURL= request.getRequestURL().substring(request.getRequestURL().lastIndexOf("/")+1) ;
    System.out.println("Link value in admin acton requestURL!!!!!!!!!"+requestURL);
    if(request.getQueryString()!=null && !("").equals(request.getQueryString())){
        url = relativeURL+requestURL+"?"+request.getQueryString();
    }else{
        url = relativeURL+requestURL+"?"+request.getQueryString();
    }

    System.out.println("url :  "+url);
    if(links!=null && links.get("user")== null ){
        links.put("user",url);
        //session.setAttribute("links", links);
    }
    return mapping.findForward("user");
}
```

I am able to login , LoginAction is working fine but if i click hyperlink it shows :

"HTTP Status 500 - No action instance for path /userAction could be created "

Comment: Check the logs. Determine if you really need to override the constructor. Etc.

Comment: Hi Dave, Do you have any example or any refrence where i can get some idea to acheive this.

Comment: You do not need to use parameter="page" in struts-config.xml. Your request object will hold the parameter. Also if you are using DispatchAction, then your method name should be parameter name. And if you are not using DispatchAction, then your method name should be execute.

Comment: Hi Guys if you know any link where i can get a simple exapmle for Struts integration with Hibernate So that will help me a lot to understand more.

Comment: Facing Error : INFO: Marking servlet action as unavailable
Sep 29, 2014 5:25:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /Demo threw load() exception
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Parsing error processing resource path /WEB-INF/struts-config.xml
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.handleConfigException(ActionServlet.java:739)